# How many zeros does the mathematical operation have?

Tags: number-theory

I have this statement:

> How many zeros does the mathematical operation have(total zeros anywhere)?
>
> $(10^{10} + 10^{11} + 10^{12} + ... + 10^{2009})^{2010}$

My attempt was:

$10^{20100}(1 + 10^1 + 10^2 + ... +10^{1999})^{2010} = [\underbrace{(111111......)}_\text{2000 1's}]^{2010}$

So the number is of the form $[\underbrace{(111111......)}_\text{2000 times}]^{2010}\underbrace{000.....}_\text{20100 times}$

Then the problem is reduced to how many zeroes have $[\underbrace{(111111......)}_\text{2000 times}]^{2010}$

Im stuck, any hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: That number is not divisible by $10$, so it has no $0$s

Comment: Do you mean $0$ digits at the end, or $0$ digits anywhere?

Comment: @RobertIsrael anywhere

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal $0$ anywhere

Comment: Oh, ok. In hindsight, I should have guessed that.

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to do that other than brute force: computing that big number ($4018082$ digits), converting to decimal, and counting the zeros.

Comment: You can get rather close by assuming the digits are equally distributed, which would say there should be about $401808$ zeros.  This is within about $5\%$ of the exact answer WhatsUp gives.  I am surprised it is that far off.  The normal approximation would suggest a standard deviation of about $600$

Comment: this problem is an math olympiad problem, so it must be possible without brute force

Comment: @RossMillikan I guess you forgot to add $20100$. My answer includes these zeros at the end. So it's a quite good match.

Answer (score 1):

As @RobertIsrael said, this doesn't seem doable with pen and paper.

To give some feeling of how the number $(1111\dotsc)^{2010}$ look like:

$$938763135722556498362329925501
\dotsc 858400639639147955804663695601.$$

The final answer is $421717$.

Comment: this problem is an math olympiad problem, so it must be possible without brute force

Comment: Could you give the source of the problem, or verify that the statement is correct?

Comment: my coach give me this problem

Comment: and the statement is correct

Comment: Please, do share the solution with all of us when your coach reveals it! All I can do is to confirm that the answer given here is correct.